# Can you do a DynamoDB Atomic Counter Update within a DynamoDB Transaction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Context :

I have a transaction which currently updating 3 tables with records. If I include the dynamodb update `atomic counter` within the same transaction, would decrement counter happen if the update to any of the other tables failed?

Comment: You could presumably try it to see what happens. Deliberately set an update condition within the transaction, after the atomic counter increment, that will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the transaction would roll back the update to the counter if there is a failure in updating the other tables.

Atomic Counter within a transaction here is more like conditional write within a transaction.